# Report Spam in Careers messages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs, spam

I realize that I can block an employer from contacting me. I have done so.

However, I'd like a way to report simply unfair use of the Careers systems. I received a poorly targeted recruitment attempt, I responded "Not Interested" and have received multiple followups "Can I just have a quick phone call to describe the roll..." "I'd love to tell you more..." etc.

After the second one, I found the "Block Employer" button. However, does this get any attention from the Careers site, in general? Is there any precedence for having your Careers account suspended because too many candidates have blocked you?

I'd like there to be a "Report Harassment" feature.

Comment: Go to the relevant company page, there is a "flag a problem" link in there. Otherwise, just email the careers team and give details. (Exact details better be given in private, not here on MSE in public anyway.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard there is no "flag a problem" link on the company page for the company that contacted me more than twice.